NestJS: Extracting Certificates from a calling application
I have a simple NestJS controller that looks like this:
  @Patch('/tenantMappings/:tenantId')
  @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
  async tenantMappings(
    @Param('tenantId') tenantId,
    @Body() request: RequestDto,
  ) {
    try {
      this.logger.log(
        'Provider App: Received TenantMapping Request with payload: ',
        request,
      );
      return await this.tenantMappingService.createTenantMapping(
        request
      );
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error(
        'Provider App: Error while handling tenant mapping: ',
        error.message,
      );
      return;
    }
  }

This is being called a cloud application using mTLS certificates. I would need to extract the certificate and verify that the issuer and subjectname match a given pattern.
Is there a way we can do this in NestJs?
In the Spring Boot (Java) stack. this is one way of doing this.
    public X509Certificate extractClientCertificate(HttpServletRequest request) {
        X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) request.getAttribute(JAVAX_SERVLET_REQUEST_X509_CERTIFICATE);
}

